# Apache tomcat server on Nginx keeps downloading .jsp files

Tags: jsp, tomcat, nginx

Below is the content of my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

#root /var/www/mydomain.com/html;
root /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.46/webapps/app1;
index index.jsp index.html index.htm;

server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.jsp$ {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
  expires 1M;
}
}
```

When I click on any JSP page it downloads and when HTTP request is sent to Servlet is returns `404 Not Found error`.

[image]

Comment: .html pages render with the corresponding css/js without problem

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're sending the request to nginx itself in your "proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;".

Supposing your servlet engine is listening on port 8080 on the same system, you should "proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;".

Comment: Thanks Gerald... This is fine now

Comment: if my answer was of any help, you could perhaps accept it?